# Plastic tensile bars for Tye testing

Tags: plastic

We make plastic tensile bars per astm 638. The problem that I'm having is the bars are breaking outside the gauge marks in the reduced section of the samples. I'd like to know as to what I can do to prevent this ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE. Could you provide some more details on what exactly your question is? My understanding is that you are producing plastic bars and applying tension until they fail. They are failing in a way that makes it hard for you to measure. Could you show a picture or sketch of these bars and how you're testing them?